# Yii2 Pagination + LinkPager Not Showing

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

should be a simple fix but I'm not exactly sure why my `LinkPager` isn't showing here. My controller action is:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Shout::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    $countQuery = count($query);
    $pagination = new Pagination(
        [
            'totalCount' => $countQuery,
            'pageSize' => 5
        ]
    );
    $shouts = $query->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render(
        'index',
        [
            'shouts' => $shouts,
            'pagination' => $pagination
        ]
    );

}
```

And my LinkPager widget is:

```
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
echo LinkPager::widget(
    [
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ]
);
```

And while the `pageSize` is being limited to `5`, I do not see the page selection below. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the `$query->count()` rather than `count($query);` change your line in the controller action

from

```
$countQuery = count($query);
```

to

```
$countQuery = $query->count();
```